# How to configure or setup Log4Net with ASP.NET ( included MVC) C# on Visual Studio 2012 ~ ~

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, log4net

I want to record software process logs to files. Rather than make my own log system, I am trying to use Log4Net with ASP.NET MVC, but I have run into problems setting it up in Visual Studio 2015, like:

1. How to setup web.config / Global.asax page?
2. How to install components in VS 2012 ~?
3. How to use it in my `*.cs` file?

What are the steps to properly configure Log4Net With ASP.NET MVC C# in Visual Studio 2015?

I also wrote a Q&A to set it up for ASP.NET WebForms,
 see [How to use Log4net from Nuget with Visual Studio platform in the ASP.NET Web Form (Easy method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569713/how-to-use-log4net-from-nuget-with-visual-studio-platform-in-the-asp-net-web-for).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Step1: To use the Nuget to get the log4net package:

[image]

Step2: tell log4net to initialize itself from the XML configuration (Web.config), by adding this call in the `Global.asax.cs` file under `Application_Start()`:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

[image]

Step3: add the configuration section in Web.config between tag `<configSections>...</configSections>`:

```
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
```

[image]

Step4: Insert the actual log4net configuration `<log4net>...</log4net>` (Within `<configuration>...</configuration>` but after the `</configSections>` tag) , see [Apache log4net™ Config Examples](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) for more examples:

```
<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

[image]

Now you're ready to make calls to an `ILog` to write actual log statements to the configured appender(s):

```
ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HomeController));      

public ActionResult Index()
{
    log.Debug("Debug message");
    log.Warn("Warn message");
    log.Error("Error message");
    log.Fatal("Fatal message");
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    return View();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an impelling reason for that static "Log" member? The way I see it is that all you need is the non-static member "log"...

Comment: @marco6 Hi sir thanks very much for your response for your question, I just use "static" for personal coding style , if you want to know why please check  this [URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx) thanks again

Comment: @WillieCheng My comment was about the fact that while using a static member is IMHO the most beneficial choice, your code uses a non-static instance to perform every action ("ILog log" is clearly non-static, while your static Log is never initialized). I would have done something like:
"private static ILog Log {get;}=LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HomeController));" and remove your second declaration.

Comment: +1 great answer, saved a lot of my time, just a little enhancement for devs: if you want to show the logged messages in the Visual Studio Output while debugging, use the `TraceAppender` from the apache log4net config exmaples link provided in the article :) `ConsoleAppender` did not worked for me.

Comment: not logging for me, not sure why, but no errors either

Comment: @marco6 most people who use log4net use static to keep track of what class or method called the logger.
They all start off with `private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);` as the start of every class.
use https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/ for reference, specifically he says 'Declare it as static and use this little trick so you don’t have to hard code the class type.'

Comment: @Jean-Paul agreed! That is exactly what my comment was about! :)