# How add Oracle as provider for Entity Data Model wizard

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, entity-framework

Im using Visual Studio 2017. I follow the instructions from this answer:

[Interoperate between ASP.NET MVC and Oracle DB (12c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192435/interoperate-between-asp-net-mvc-and-oracle-db-12c/36192436#36192436)

I can connect to my Oracle server using Server Explorer.

Install From Nuget

- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EnitityFramework
- Oracle.Web

[image]

But doesn't show on the Entity Data Model Wizard screen as provider.

[image]

**What I'm missing?**

Answer (score 2):

To connect to oracle with EF 6.2, first install the [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2017-3806459.html). Then add your `tnsnames.ora` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle Developer Tools for VS2017\network\admin`

Install From Nuget

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess   ,
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EnitityFramework

Once you clean and rebuild your solution you will be able to add your EF class with the Data Model Wizard.